# Hybring Typescript/Javascript build looking for file which will never exist

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsconfig, incremental-build

Running `tsc -b --verbose`, I get the following output every time:

```
 - Projects in this build: 
    * tsconfig.json

 - Project 'tsconfig.json' is out of date because output file 'dist/src/auth.js' does not exist

 - Building project './path/to/tsconfig/tsconfig.json'...
```

This file will never exist, because `src` and `dist` are sibling directories. I've looked through all of my files to try and find a module path to `dist/src/auth`, but none exist. I've also looked through the modules resolution logs and couldn't find one either.

Also, `src/auth.js` was recently migrated to be a `.ts` file.

I'm at a little bit of a loss for what could be occurring here and any suggestions would be highly appreciated!